# lwc combobox not aligning properly inside a lightning-layout-item

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

I am having an issue with `lightining-layout-items`. My two "inner" items are not aligned properly. think this is because I am iterating through each row.

For both the medical and form `combo-boxes` I want to have a `text-align: left` output where they are aligned independently of the how long the Name column is.

[image]

Parent Component:

```
 <template if:true={responseback}>
      <lightning-layout multiple-rows horizontal-align="spread">
          <template for:each={students} for:item="student">
              <lightning-layout-item size="12" key={student.id} class="slds-p-around_small">
                  <c-child-form
                    application-id={student.Id}
                    first-name={student.TargetX_SRMb__Contact__r.FirstName} 
                    last-name={student.TargetX_SRMb__Contact__r.LastName}
                    medical-pick-list-value={student.AIS_Medical_Release__c}
                    travel-pick-list-value={student.AIS_Travel_Form_Received__c}
                  ></c-child-form>
              </lightning-layout-item>
          </template>
      </lightning-layout>
    </template>
```

Child Component

```
<template>
  <lightning-card>
    <lightning-layout horizontal-align="spread">
      <lightning-layout-item flexibility="3">
        <lightning-formatted-name
          first-name={firstName}
          last-name={lastName}
          id={applicationId}
          style="font-size: 20px"
        >
        </lightning-formatted-name>
      </lightning-layout-item>
      <lightning-layout-item size="4">
        <template if:true={medicalReleasePickListValues.data}>
          <lightning-combobox
            name="medicalPicklist"
            label="Medical Form"
            value={medicalPickListValue}
            options={medicalReleasePickListValues.data.values}
            onchange={handleChangeMedical}
          >
          </lightning-combobox>
        </template>
      </lightning-layout-item>
      <lightning-layout-item size="4">
        <template if:true={travelReleasePickListValues.data}>
          <lightning-combobox
            name="travelPicklist"
            label="Travel Form"
            value={travelPickListValue}
            options={travelReleasePickListValues.data.values}
            onchange={handleChangeTravel}
          >
          </lightning-combobox>
        </template>
      </lightning-layout-item>
      <lightning-layout-item flexibility="shrink">
        <lightning-button-icon
          icon-name="utility:save"
          alternative-text="Save"
          class="slds-m-left_xx-small"
          title="Save"
          onclick={submitFormData}
        ></lightning-button-icon>
      </lightning-layout-item>
    </lightning-layout>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Comment: How are you iterating it can you add that code as well? I think you are creating a separate layout on each iteration.

Comment: Hi @rahulgawale I have updated the question. I am using a parent component and passing the props down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `flexibility="3"`, **columns grow or shrink equally as space allows**. You need to see the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-layout-item/specification) to understand it better. Remove `flexibility` attribute from all items.

For flexibility,

> Make the item fluid so that it absorbs any extra space in its
>   container or shrinks when there is less space. Allowed values are:
>   auto (columns grow or shrink equally as space allows),
>   shrink (columns shrink equally as space decreases),
>   no-shrink (columns don't shrink as space reduces),
>   grow (columns grow equally as space increases),
>   no-grow (columns don't grow as space increases),
>   no-flex (columns don't grow or shrink as space changes).
>   Use a comma-separated value for multiple options, such as 'auto, no-shrink'.

I would suggest you use `size` instead. Size you have 4 columns, you can use `size="3"` for equal width columns. Each row is divided into 12 sizes. Go through [grid-system](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/) to understand better.

Note that when you use `multiple-rows` on layout, whatever crosses 12 sizes will go into next row, or else will stay in same row.

Comment: This worked! Your explanation makes perfect sense and helped solve my issue.